# Ubuntu VPS 18.04 server Apache2 Domain Alias

Tags: server, alias, vps, domain-server

I hope someone can help me some. I believe this is an easy problem. I currently have a VPS running ubnuntu 18.04 server and Apache2 . I have prestashop installed and trying to configure the multi store options. Each store has to be an domain alias of the main.  For example;
some.1store.com (main store)
some.2store.com (multi store)
some.3store.com (multi store)

I would need the 2store and 3store to be aliases of 1store . This is easy to do in cpanel or plesk. I currently do not have any control panel installed and prefer to complete this task ssh . To save resources and learn the in's and out's.

I tried editing the /etc/apach2/sites-available/2store.com.conf  .    ServerName 1store.com but that did not work . My next plan was to edit the 1store.com.conf and add 2store.com and 3store.com as a DomainAlias . I than figured I would just ask here before I keep messing with files. Any help will be appreciated.

All domains are pointed to my server.

I do value your time. I am pretty new to ubuntu and servers (hence my newbie status here) and wish I could offer help to these forums but just dont have enough knowledge to contribute. If your close to chicagoland I can offer mechanical assistance or some beer :) .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.

Simply add the domains you want to be an alias to the .conf file of the main domain. Example. 1store.com , 2store.com 3store.com . To make 2store.com and 3 store.com an alias of 1store.com edit 1store.com.conf and add DomainAlias 2store.com 3store.com www.2tore.com www.3store.com .

Simple problem that took me awhile. Hope it helps someone out there.